Python wont add integer if break is executed
So im very very new to Python and for my Psychology class I have to recreate an adaptive Big Five personality test in python Replit, to do so I need to add or subtract values unto each integer value (Openness,Neuroticism,Extraversion etc) without the break it adds this up just fine, however with the break added at the end of the test the value of the integer is always 0. I dont think i can just remove the break because it would keep the loop working right?(Also my teacher requires me to use breaks at some point for a passing grade) How can I fix this?
Note: I need the entire script within a while loop Restartmodule so that after the test i can ask ''Do you wish to redo a part of the test) which then loops it back with continue;
I tried playing around with the inditments as it may also be causing issues

while Restartmodule == False:
  # Hier kan de gebruiker kiezen welk deel van persoonlijkheidtest hij of zij wil meten, of de gehele test
  BigFiveVraag1 = input(
      "Welk deel van de Big Five wilt u maken? (Openness/Conscientiousness/Agreeableness/Extraversion/Neuroticism/Alles)"
  )
  while BigFiveVraag1 != "Openness" or "Conscientiousness" or "Agreeableness" or "Extraversion" or "Neuroticism" or "Alles":
    #Adaptiviteit wordt hier gemaakt door een series van if-statements die booleans aan of uit zetten liggend aan het antwoord van de gebruiker
    #Deze booleans bepalen later in de test welke vragen geladen worden en welke overgeslagen worden (sneller/specifieker)
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Openness":
      Openness_bool = True
      Conscientiousness_bool = False
      Extraversion_bool = False
      Agreeableness_bool = False
      Neuroticism_bool = False
      print("Laad Openness vragen...")
      break
      #Conscientiousness zet alleen conscientiousness op true en de rest op false (dit is zo bij elk antwoord behalve Anders)
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Conscientiousness":
      Openness_bool = False
      Conscientiousness_bool = True
      Extraversion_bool = False
      Agreeableness_bool = False
      Neuroticism_bool = False
      print("Laad Conscientiousness vragen...")
      break
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Agreeableness":
      Openness_bool = False
      Conscientiousness_bool = False
      Extraversion_bool = False
      Agreeableness_bool = True
      Neuroticism_bool = False
      print("Laad Agreeableness vragen...")
      break
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Extraversion":
      Openness_bool = False
      Conscientiousness_bool = False
      Extraversion_bool = True
      Agreeableness_bool = False
      Neuroticism_bool = False
      print("Laad Extraversion vragen...")
      break
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Neuroticism":
      Openness_bool = False
      Conscientiousness_bool = False
      Extraversion_bool = False
      Agreeableness_bool = False
      Neuroticism_bool = True
      print("Laad Neuroticism vragen...")
      break
      #Door het kiezen van alles word elke boolean true waardoor elke vraag geladen wordt
    if BigFiveVraag1 == "Alles":
      Openness_bool = True
      Conscientiousness_bool = True
      Extraversion_bool = True
      Agreeableness_bool = True
      Neuroticism_bool = True
      #Deze boolean is uniek voor het antwoord Alles, omdat alle scores geprint moeten worden op het einde.
      PRINT_ALLSCORES = True
      print("Laad de gehele test...")
      break
    else:
      BigFiveVraag1 = input(
          "Welk deel van de Big Five wilt u maken? (Openness/Conscientiousness/Agreeableness/Extraversion/Neuroticism/Alles)"
      )
       #NEUROTICISMVRAAG1
  if Neuroticism_bool == True:
    NeuroticismVraag1 = input("Ik maak me veel zorgen.")
    while NeuroticismVraag1 not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
      #NeuroticismVraag1 = input("Ik maak me veel zorgen.")
      # Helemaal Oneens - 2 score
     if NeuroticismVraag1 == "1":
        Neuroticism -= 2
        break
  # Oneens - 1 score
    if NeuroticismVraag1 == "2":
        Neuroticism -= 1
        break
  # Neutraal - 0 score
    if NeuroticismVraag1 == "3":
        Neuroticism += 0
        break
  # Eens + 1 score
    if NeuroticismVraag1 == "4":
        Neuroticism += 1
        break
  # Helemaal Eens + 2 score
    if NeuroticismVraag1 == "5":
        Neuroticism += 2
        #elke vraag heeft een break om uit de while loop te komen zodra de if-statement voltooid is.
        break


There are several problems in this code (some are just bad/inefficient style, and some are bugs).  The most obvious bug is a common beginner's mistake:  x == "a" or "b" or "c" doesn't do what you think.  It's equivalent to (x == "a") or "b" or "c" and is always true.  Instead, use x == "a" or x == "b" or x == "c".  Or you can use x in ("a", "b", "c").  See this post for details.

Welcome to SO. This site works best with problems condensed into a [mre]. See [ask]. "Fix my code" kind of questions don't work well, here. Feel free to ask more questions with one issue at a time. Most likely, you should be able to find an answer to each of your questions on this site.
